# Using html placeholder with non latin letters

Tags: html

I am using `placerholder=""` like this to show the users which word they have to translate: `<input id="ha_1" placeholder="안녕하세요"  type="text">` The Korean word 안녕하세요 displays perfectly in chrome, but gets messed up by Firefox and Edge (both newest version). It looks like this:
[image: placeholder in edge/firefox]

Any way to fix this directly or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: what is the page encoding set to

Comment: where can I check that? for test purposes I just used a blank .html file without any specifications

Comment: google helps. I put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` before the html code and it works... thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: glad that I could help :)

Comment: refer the answer given for your question please. :)

Comment: Just a tip. This is the 21st century, so _always use unicode in your pages_. It will help not only for non-English languages, but also for English punctuation, special characters, and, if it’s your thing, emoji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `Character Encoding` type inside of your html code.

> **What is Character Encoding?**
>
> ASCII was the first character encoding
>   standard (also called character set). ASCII defined 127 different
>   alphanumeric characters that could be used on the internet: numbers
>   (0-9), English letters (A-Z), and some special characters like ! $ + -
>   ( ) @ < > .
>
> ANSI (Windows-1252) was the original Windows character set, with
>   support for 256 different character codes.
>
> ISO-8859-1 was the default character set for HTML 4. This character
>   set also supported 256 different character codes.
>
> Because ANSI and ISO-8859-1 were so limited, the default character
>   encoding was changed to UTF-8 in HTML5.
>
> **UTF-8 (Unicode) covers almost all of the characters and symbols in the
>   world.**

for more information refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp).

Please use as following meta tag inside of your `<head>` tag.

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

complete example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Character Encoding</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>안녕하세요</h1>
  <input id="ha_1" placeholder="안녕하세요" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```